# Unhandled exception, even after adding try-catch block ? C++

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, unhandled

```
try
{
    bool numericname=false;
    std::cout <<"\n\nEnter the Name of Customer: ";
    std::getline(cin,Name);
    std::cout<<"\nEnter the Number of Customer: ";
    std::cin>>Number;
    std::string::iterator i=Name.begin();
    while(i!=Name.end())
    {
        if(isdigit(*i))
        {
            numericname=true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    if(numericname)
    {
        throw "Name cannot be numeric.";
    }
} catch(string message)
{
    cout<<"\nError Found: "<< message <<"\n\n";
}
```

Why am I getting unhandled exception error ? Even after I have added the catch block to catch thrown string messages?

Comment: try sometihng like `catch (char* msg)` or `catch (const char* msg)`

Comment: (char* message)  worked !!! :D But what was the problem with the previous code ? I did add #include<string>

Comment: check answer for `std::string`

Answer (score 3):

`"Name cannot be numeric."` is not a `std::string`, it's a `const char*`, so you need to catch it like this:

```
try
{
    throw "foo";
}
catch (const char* message)
{
    std::cout << message;
}
```

To catch "foo" as `std::string` you need to throw/catch it like this:

```
try
{
    throw std::string("foo");
}
catch (std::string message)
{
    std::cout << message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should send an `std::exception` instead, like `throw std::logic_error("Name cannot be numeric")`
you could then catch it with polymorphsim and the underlying type of your throw will no more be a problem :

```
try
{
    throw std::logic_error("Name cannot be numeric"); 
    // this can later be any type derived from std::exception
}
catch (std::exception& message)
{
    std::cout << message.what();
}
```